# Reset password in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

So I am working on a custom authentication in oracle apex. In that, I want to add reset password function so I used the `Pl/SQL` function for reset password first it validates the user by user's email and then it sends the link to the email, in that it redirects to the users reset the password region there it shows this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvGCB.png). For a long time this error is showing and I don't know how to fix this ...... this is the custom authentication code

```
    create or replace function  MY_AUTHENTICATION
    (p_username in VARCHAR2,
    p_password in VARCHAR2)
    return BOOLEAN
    is
        l_user USER_TABLE.user_name%type := upper(p_username);
        l_hash USER_TABLE.set_password%type;
        begin
            select user_name, set_password 
            into l_user, l_hash
            from USER_TABLE
            where user_name = p_username and set_password = p_password;
                RETURN TRUE;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
        THEN
            RETURN FALSE;                 
    end;
```

and this is my reset password code

```
    BEGIN
    
        APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.SET_USER('COMIDA');
        APEX_CUSTOM_AUTH.LOGIN(
                                    P_UNAME => 'COMIDA',
                                    P_PASSWORD =>'1234567890',
                                    P_SESSION_ID => :SESSION,
                                    P_APP_PAGE  => :APP_ID
                 );
    
    APEX_UTIL.RESET_PASSWORD(
                                    P_USER_NAME => UPPER(:P15_USER_NAME),
                                    P_OLD_PASSWORD => NULL,
                                    P_NEW_PASSWORD=> :P15_PASSWORD,
                                    P_CHANGE_PASSWORD_ON_FIRST_USE => FALSE    
                        );
        
     
    APEX_AUTHENTICATION.LOGOUT(:SESSION,:APP_ID);
    END;
```

Comment: Run the page in debug mode or - alternatively - execute the resetting password procedure in SQL*Plus to see what's going on.

Comment: Could you share the debug screen to see the error in detail? At least the error ORA CODE

Comment: The apex_util.reset_password is for 'Application Express Accounts' authentication scheme, it will have no knowledge of your custom table.

Comment: "COMIDA" is not an administrator - this the error showing when I debugged and Comida is the schema

Comment: @scott what should i use instead of apex_util.reset_password

Comment: If you own the table that stores the user credentials, then you should write your own process to reset a password. Note that resetting a password securely is a challenge. Typically, apex authentication is used for development and once production is reached an external method of authentication is used (like oracle SSO), so you don't have to worry about that piece of the security. If you have a choice, consider that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have your users in a custom table and you want to change the password of Oracle APEX Users? That users are stored in the default schema APEX_00000 (whatever version that APEX you've installed).

So, in order to change the password in your application of your custom table you must do this

```
update USER_TABLE
set password = l_hash
where user_name = l_user;
```

Don't confuse APEX Credentials with Custom Auth.